# Wait for preceding Complete.ContinueWith to complete

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow

**EDIT SOLUTION:** It appears the solution is to have code like below where I specify TaskContinuationOption.ExecuteSynchronously

```
    public ActionBlock<DomainBaseFile[]> GetActionBlock()
    {
        var returnActionBlock = new ActionBlock<DomainBaseFile[]>(
            n => Work(n)
        );
        returnActionBlock.Completion.ContinueWith((s, o) => FinalizeFiles(), new object(), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        return returnActionBlock;
    }
```

I have two tasks, FirstTask and SecondTask that are linked.  Both tasks have things they have to do on completion i.e

```
firstTask.Complete.ContinueWith(t => ...
```

The problem I'm currently having is that the SecondTask Complete.ContinueWith seems to be running before the FirstTask.Complete.ContinueWith and the code is built assuming that First task is done.

I assume this is because the ContinueWith task runs whenever after the Completion signal is sent and isn't subject to ordering like the Complete propagation is.

Is there anyway for me to force SecondTask to not call it's Complete method till the FirstTask.Complete.ContinueWith is done?

Currently, I have

```
   Task.WhenAll(firstBlock.Completion)
        .ContinueWith(_ => 
            secondBlock.Complete()
   );
```

However, this Task.WhenAll is going to wait for the Completion and not the Completion.ContinueWith function to finish.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this day and age of `async/await` you should do away of _neck to knee_ swimming attire and `ContinueWith`

Comment: The doco clearly states _"Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed"_.  Are you sure about your observation?

Comment: If you want to ensure that `FirstTask` is complete then you should straight up just do `await firstTask;  await secondTask;` because by definition you don't want parallel operations to occur

Comment: @MickyD Neck-To-Knee?

Comment: You may want to check out [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), an API for data pipelines.